# How can I define a variable name in compliance with MISRA 2012 Rule 5.2?

Tags: c, misra

How can I define a variable name in compliance with MISRA 2012 Rule 5.2, checking if it is defined then defining it using `#ifndef` and `#define`?

```
#ifndef Variablename
#define Variablename
#endif
```

The variable name is identical in Line 1 and 2 and has 68 characters in it:

```
ASDFED_LOYUTIONS_ANNA_FIVEW_OUI_1119ba60_7496_11e9_8ca0_4cbb586a0889
```

It should be in compliance with Misra 2012 standards Rule 5.2, but when I try to use it, the compliance tester throws an error (identifier clash) that it is not in compliance with [MISRA 2012 Rule 5.1, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 5.2, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 5.4, required], [MISRA 2012 Rule 5.5, required].

Comment: The limit for C99 is 63 characters; you can't readily use 68-character names.  Rethink why you have such a long name and decide whether to ignore MISRA, or avoid embedding the fully-punctuated UUID in the name (omit the underscores) or shorten some of the prefix wordiness, or all of the above.

Comment: MISRA 2012 rule 5.2 explicitly says _This rule does not apply if either identifier is a macro identifier because this case is covered by Rule 5.4 and Rule 5.5._  Similarly, Rule 5.1 does not apply because the identifier is not an external identifier.  Rule 5.4 does apply; it requires macro identifiers to be distinct.  Rule 5.5 does apply; it requires that identifiers shall be distinct from macro names.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You _can't_ check if variables are defined with pre-processor #ifndef and that has nothing to do with MISRA. Please clarify: is your obscenely long identifier a _variable_ or is it a _pre-processor definition_?

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the MISRA C 2012 document for rule 5.2

> In C90 the minimum requirement is that the first 31 characters are significant;
>
> In C99 the minimum requirement is that the first 63 characters are significant, with each
> universal character or extended source character counting as a single character.

So, depending on your implementation you cannot have another identifier with first 31 or 63 characters the same. I suggest that you look into renaming the variable.

Comment: Note that rule 5.2 explicitly does not apply when either identifier is a macro name.  It is Rule 5.4 and Rule 5.5 that apply when one or both of the names are macro identifiers.

Comment: #ifndef  ASDFED_LOYUTIONS_ANNA_FIVEW_OUI_1119ba60_7496_11e9_8ca0_4cbb586a0889     #define  ASDFED_LOYUTIONS_ANNA_FIVEW_OUI_1119ba60_7496_11e9_8ca0_4cbb586a0889  Can it be changed to                                                           #ifndef cbb586a0889                                                            #define cbb586a0889.                                                                 Is this in compliance with MISRA 2012 5.1,5.2, 5.3 and 5.4 ?

Comment: Yes, `#ifndef cbb586a0889 #define cbb586a0889` will be compliant with 5.1, 5.2, 5.4. Rule 5.3 deals with hiding an identifier in inner or outer scope and needs more context.

Comment: Except you _can't_ use variables in `#ifndef` experssions. The question cannot be answered because it is unclear what the OP is even trying to do.